# How do I call a method from an imported class in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have some code which fetches an XML file from a URL and then parses it using NSXMLParser.  Currently this code is contained within the viewController which calls it.  I would like, for re-usability sake, to move the parsing code to an external class and call it from the viewController.

I tried to achieve this as follows:

Created a blank NSObject class file, put the parsing code into the .h and .m files, then used an `#import` statement in my viewController.m file and an `@Class` statement in the viewController.h file so I could call the methods from within the viewController class.

I'm not sure how to proceed or whether I'm approaching this the wrong way, please advise.

---

I instantiate the external class with the following line in the `@interface` of my viewController

```
XMLParser *xmlParser;
```

In viewDidLoad for my viewController class I call a method I have written in XMLParser.m.  The call is performed as follows:

```
[xmlParser fetchXML];
```

The problem is that when I compile I get the following warning:

```
'XMLParser' may not respond to '-fetchXML'
```

When the view loads at runtime the method isn't called, or it's called but doesn't run

Comment: Is the code placed in a class method (begins with a +) or an instance method (begins with a -)? How do you call the method? What happens when you compile and what happens when it runs?

Comment: Sounds like everything is correct. What's the problem?

Comment: Did you allocate and initialize xmlParser? A message to a NULL object is a no-op.

Comment: Thanks @fbrereto, that was the final problem.  Great stuff ;o)

All working now thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a file called `XMLParser.h` that includes something like:

```
@interface XMLParser : NSObject
{
    ...
}   
- (void)fetchXML;
```

Then in `viewController.m`, there should be:

```
#import "XMLParser.h"
```

I would suspect you're missing one of these steps.

Comment: Thanks @Rob Napier, no compile errors, I was missing the `-(void)fetchXML;`

However, my method still doesn't seem to be getting called at runtime.  I can post more code if it helps

Comment: If your method is not being called, the most common reason is that your pointer is that xmlParser is nil. Sending a message to nil does not generate an error, but it does nothing.